# Firefox Download

Tags: firefox

https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2016/11/15/latest-firefox-launches-today/

This is the new version of firefox. Can anyone help me to download it on my ubuntu 12.04? I am new on linux.

Answer (score 2):

B. Ubuntu’s case, Linux Mint and Debian

1. Ubuntu: no ubuntu-mozilla-daily ppa!

   Many howtos on this subject will tell you to install Firefox pre-versions through Mozilla’s ppa ubuntu-mozilla-daily. Using this ppa will not only install the latest Firefox 52 daily build, once called “minefield” – updated daily! It will also update your current Firefox and Thunderbird to test versions.

   These testing versions are not meant to be stable or usable.
   → Avoid this ppa unless you know exactly what you’re doing!
2. The official Firefox Beta ppa: mozillateam firefox-next

   The firefox-next ppa will replace your current Firefox installation with the current available version in Mozillas Beta channel. Simply run these two commands in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

   You may also have a look at the Firefox Aurora ppa.

   Note: you can use only one of these three channels (Aurora, Beta, and Daily) at the same time!
3. Official Ubuntu updates for Firefox (automatic)

   Ubuntu automatically updates its repositories to the newest stable Firefox version a few days after the official release (as does Linux Mint). Here are a few examples of how many days Ubuntu and Linux Mint need to push the update:

   Ubuntu: Firefox 47 was released on June 7, 2016. The update showed up on June 13, only 6 days after the official Firefox release.
   Linux Mint: Firefox 48 was released on August 2, 2016. MintUpdate dispatched the update on August 7, only 5 days after the official release.

Source: [libre-software.net: How to install FireFox on Linux Mint, Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS, Fedora…](http://libre-software.net/how-to-install-firefox-on-ubuntu-linux-mint/)

Comment: Yes, got the update. :)